# Correct way to make a script async call in jQuery, after DOMContentLoaded?

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance

I'm trying to work out the best way to rewrite some code. Basically, we have some adverts that are loaded via AJAX once the page has loaded (not high priority, so we don't want it to hold the DOM rendering up). This is what I see in the network tools in Firefox:

[image]

This is the current code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    ....
    $.getJSON("/cgi-bin/links/spots_load_new.cgi", {
        catid: category_id,
        linkid: link_id,
        t: temp_set
    }, function(results) {
        showSpots(results);
    });

});
```

...and this is what I thought would work after reading about `$.when()` - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    ....   
    $.when(
        $.getJSON("/cgi-bin/links/spots_load_new.cgi", {
                catid: category_id,
            linkid: link_id,
            t: temp_set,
        })
    ).then( function(results)  {
        showSpots(results);
    });
});
```

However, the items still seem to be called before the **DOMContentReady**. How to get about this?

Comment: Wrap that code block in `$(window).on('load', function() { /* your code... */ });`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks - that did it!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, note that the two code blocks in your question are equivalent. If you want to execute that code after all other content in the page has loaded, then you can hook to the `load` event of the `window`, like this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $.getJSON("/cgi-bin/links/spots_load_new.cgi", {
    catid: category_id,
    linkid: link_id,
    t: temp_set
  }, function(results) {
    showSpots(results);
  });
});

$(function() {
  // your other jQuery code...
});
```

Comment: thanks. I thought the $.when() function would cause something to run, but not hold back the page rendering. I didn't realise there was a difference between `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).on("load")`

Comment: As the request is asynchronous `$.when` has no effect like that. Yep, the difference is that document.ready fires when the DOM is ready (although stylesheets, images etc may still be loaded) and window.load fires once all content is loaded.

Comment: I can't believe the difference in speed this simple tweak has made! We went from 1.75s DOM, 2.79 load and 3.47 finished - to 1.09s DOM, 1.82s load and 2.38s fully loaded! Thats almost a whole second off :) I'll be interested to see how this affects the values on Pingdom

Comment: @AndrewNewby I also can't believe, deffering one ajax request shouldn't make that difference. Especially change in DOM time is weird as in both `$(document).ready` and `$(window).load` cases ajax is fired after `DOMcontentLoaded`. Could you tell me which benchmark are you using?

Comment: @pwolaq it was actually 2 separate requests. Each loading some JSON, and then putting content into the page. They were only adverts though, so not important enough to make the page wait. I am just using FireFox Network tools to look at the page load times (and doing it in private windows, to avoid caching). I guess the real test will to be seeing how it works with real visitors in Pingdom. Will keep you posted!

Comment: @pwolaq - as an update. Our pingdom stats are certainly showing an increase in speed. The site load times have gone from 1.9s avg, to 1.75s ... so not too shabby just for a couple of AJAX calls being made to run after the page rendering!

Answer (score 2):

Your two codes do exactly the same.

You need to wrap your code with `$(document).ready` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // $.getJSON...
});
```

Comment: Or the shorthand:

$(function() {
    // Code here
});

Comment: @pwolaq - thanks, but I already have that :) I didn't mention it, as I thought it was a bit basic... but I will update my question